# Trying to add a report, but I keep getting this privelages error in Cuba Studio

Tags: jpa, jpql, cuba-platform

Can somebody help me why I get this error.

SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: REPORT_GROUP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to update database from Studio menu: Run -> Update database. After that restart the application.